How to find the fluctuation in the average
Assume I have N random points, with the error for just one of these points being infinite. What will be the error on the average of the sample?
Typically, this problem can be solved by calculating the RMS error of the sample. However, in this case, the RMS error would be excessively large due to the infinite error of a single point. It's unreasonable for one point to dominate the error of the entire sample.
